# Flexbox keep wrapping point while increasing item width

Tags: html, css

First of all, here is a [codepen](https://codepen.io/mihael-munta/pen/VwbaBBN) with the issue I am trying to solve.

This is a simplified version of the problem I have on an actual project. My goal is to keep the grid in the same format with 5 columns and to be able to increase the width of these cells so the content is always visible, but also so that it doesn't wrap before the first row of 5 columns is displayed. Whenever I try to increase the width of the cells the grid wraps and I lose the structure I want.

So, basically, increase width of items, but prevent wrapping, is it possible? It is fine if the content overflows the flex container itself, the goal is to add overflow-x to this grid.

```css
.flex-container {
  border: 1px solid silver;
  display: flex;
  width: 50%;
}

.wrap {
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.wrap div {
  background: gold;
}

.flex-item {
  width: 160px;
  border-bottom: 1px solid black;
  border-right: 1px solid black;
  line-height: 100px;
  color: black;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 2em;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="flex-container wrap">
  <div class="flex-item">11111111111111</div>
  <div class="flex-item">22222222222222</div>
  <div class="flex-item">33333333333333</div>
  <div class="flex-item">44444444444444</div>
  <div class="flex-item">55555555555555</div>
  <div class="flex-item">66666666666666</div>
  <div class="flex-item">77777777777777</div>
  <div class="flex-item">88888888888888</div>
  <div class="flex-item">99999999999999</div>
  <div class="flex-item">00000000000000</div>
</div>
```

Comment: I'm not entirely sure what it is that you want to achieve but, you can set your container to something like`width:100%` then you can set the children's  to `width: calc(100% / 5)` and get five columns.

Comment: @10110 No extension of the container's width is allowed except for adding overflow-x.

Comment: I also do not really understand what you're after . would : `/* extra ? */
  max-width:20%;
  box-sizing:border-box;
  text-overflow:ellipsis;
  overflow:hidden;` added to `.flex-item` class be somehow closer to your expected result ? https://jsfiddle.net/zvxo2bs5/

Comment: Would a [CSS grid](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Grid_Layout)-based approach be acceptable, or is `flex` required?

Comment: @10110 look at the codepen I supplied. Extend the width of items in the grid so that full content is visible, prevent wrapping to new row(because item width will increase) and add a horizontal scroll

Comment: for the grid option : https://jsfiddle.net/zvxo2bs5/1/ . if anything not what you look for from the two fiddle i proposed for clarification, please clarify what's not okay with your expected result ;)

Comment: @G-Cyrillus this is exactly what I want! Post an answer please.

Comment: @G-Cyrillus though this is not flex anymore. How to achieve exactly that using flexbox?

Comment: You cannot, that's why you have flex or grid. If you really need flex, then you need 2 containers but even then, columns won't be matching. `flex` is a **1D** grid, `grid` is a **2D** grid ;) 2 different purposes

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the comments, it does look like grid is the option you need, it won't allow content to be wrapping and justify content will stick it on the side if shorter thant the width of the container.

here is the snippet with grid:

```css
/* flex turned into grid */
.flex-container {
  border: 1px solid silver;
              display: grid;
              grid-template-columns:repeat(5,auto);
              justify-content:start;
  overflow:auto;
  width: 80%;
  
}

.wrap {

}

.wrap div {
  background: gold;
}

.flex-item {
  border-bottom: 1px solid black;
  border-right: 1px solid black;
  line-height: 100px;
  color: black;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 2em;
  text-align: center; 
}
```

```html
<div class="flex-container wrap">
  <div class="flex-item">11111111111111</div>
  <div class="flex-item">22222222222222</div>
  <div class="flex-item">33333333333333</div>
  <div class="flex-item">44444444444444</div>
  <div class="flex-item">55555555555555</div>
  <div class="flex-item">66666666666666</div>
  <div class="flex-item">77777777777777</div>
  <div class="flex-item">88888888888888</div>
  <div class="flex-item">99999999999999</div>
  <div class="flex-item">00000000000000</div>
</div>
```

Comment: So just to confirm, this is 100% not possible via flex?

Comment: @MichaelMunta no its not unless dispatching the two rows into 2 flex containers and setting fixed width for the items or setting the width to the children via javascript to  look like columns. also flex-wrap will wrap instead showing a scrollbar ;) Honestly, flex is not at its best for this kind of layout.

Answer (score 1):

I think, if it is allowable, that [css grid](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Grid_Layout) may be a better candidate for the layout you are proposing...

```css
.grid-container {
  border: 1px solid silver;
  display: grid;
  width: 50%;
  grid-template-columns: 20% 20% 20% 20% 20%; /* hard set five columns and no more */
}

.grid-container div {
  background: gold;
}

.grid-item {
  /* width: 160px; */
  border-bottom: 1px solid black;
  border-right: 1px solid black;
  line-height: 100px;
  color: black;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 2em;
  text-align: center;
  overflow-x: hidden; /* overflow-x to hide overflow as discussed in question */
}
```

```html
<div class="grid-container">
  <div class="grid-item">11111111111111</div>
  <div class="grid-item">22222222222222</div>
  <div class="grid-item">33333333333333</div>
  <div class="grid-item">44444444444444</div>
  <div class="grid-item">55555555555555</div>
  <div class="grid-item">66666666666666</div>
  <div class="grid-item">77777777777777</div>
  <div class="grid-item">88888888888888</div>
  <div class="grid-item">99999999999999</div>
  <div class="grid-item">00000000000000</div>
</div>
```

Comment: not too sure about what the ops wants, 5 on a row but 160px of width ... and overflow-x ? turns the grid to `repeat(5, what ??? 160px, 20%, auto or else magic number )` ;)

Comment: @G-Cyrillus - Oooof, good catch, thanks. Regardless, I think I may just retract/delete this answer; I'm not 100% confident in what the OP wants. I took a chance based on a hunch, but now I'm wondering if it would e best removed and instead we push for clarity.

Comment: I kinda need it to be flex because the grid in question is complex and it would take me a lot of time to turn it into a CSS grid. The width of the items doesn't need to be fixed. Only the container is fixed.

Comment: @MichaelMunta - unfortunately, I'm dubious that the conditions you have stated are going to end up being compatible with `flex`-- you might do better to spend the time correcting for a better solution.  Regardless, the requirements are a bit unclear in the question.  If you could create a succinct list of your requirements, and perhaps an image of the desired outcome, it might help you get more answers that are suited to your specific situation.

Comment: I think your answer is pertinent, from the description we understand, it is obviously not a flex layout, and from the source, only grid can achieve 5 elements on a row matching columns too ... i guess the 160px here was that attempt ;)

Answer (score 0):

```css
.flex-container {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  background-color:red;
}

.flex-container > div {
  background-color: #f1f1f1;
  width: 100px;
  margin: 10px;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 75px;
  font-size: 30px;
   word-wrap: break-word;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>

</head>
<body>

<div class="flex-container">
  <div>11111111111111</div>
  <div>22222222222222</div>
  <div>33333333333333</div>
  <div>44444444444444</div>
  <div>55555555555555</div>
  <div>66666666666666</div>
  <div>77777777777777</div>
  <div>88888888888888</div>
  <div>99999999999999</div>
  <div>00000000000000</div>
   
</div>


</body>
```

Comment: No, there have to be 5 columns top and 5 columns bottom. No extension of flex container's width is allowed. Just to extend the width of the items and add an overflow-x to the container.

Comment: I have added new IMG in my answer check once and let me know